# Selected Marked elements are not writing in new document

Tags: vb.net

This code was working and now it's not. I have no idea why. What the code is supposed to do is take all content after  to  and paste write it to a new file.

Right now it's grabbing all the text regardless of the start/stop markers

I've tried changing the insideBlock to true or false. I've also tried changing the source document to make sure the comment markers are right.

Here's my code

```
    Dim startMark As String = "<!--#start#-->"
    Dim stopMark As String = "<!--#stop#-->"
    searchDir = txtDirectory.Text
    Prefix = txtBxUnique.Text
For Each singleFile In allFiles
    If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
        Dim fileName = singleFile.FullName
        Debug.Print("file name : " & fileName)
        ' A backup first    
        Dim backup As String = fileName & ".bak"
        File.Copy(fileName, backup, True)

        ' Load lines from the source file in memory
        Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(backup)

        ' Now re-create the source file and start writing lines inside a block
        Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
            For Each line As String In lines
                If line = startMark Then
                    ' start writing at the line below
                    insideBlock = True
                ElseIf line = stopMark Then
                    ' Stop writing
                    insideBlock = False
                ElseIf insideBlock = True Then
                    ' Write the current line in the block
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End If
Next
```

Here's source data

```
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2010, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN" [
<!ENTITY graphic3-16_dgcs_file_window SYSTEM  Graphics\3-16_dgcs_file_window.cgm" NDATA cgm>
<!ENTITY graphic19000_2 SYSTEM "Graphics\19000_2.cgm" NDATA cgm> ]>
<?Pub UDT _bookmark _target>
<?Pub EntList alpha bull copy rArr sect trade deg>
<?Pub Inc>
<doc service="af" docid="TO 1Q-1(M)B-2-2-12-1" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="2" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<tmidno></tmidno>
<chgnum></chgnum>
<chgdate></chgdate>
<chghistory>
<chginfo>
<chgtxt></chgtxt>
<date></date></chginfo></chghistory>
<doctype></doctype>
<maintlvl></maintlvl>
<!--#start#-->
<prtitle>
<subject>
Trying to get this code to work</subject></prtitle>
<mfr></mfr>
<contractno>A12345</contractno>
<contractno>B12</contractno>
<!--#start#-->
<line></line>
<contractno>Contract No</contractno>
<supersed></supersed>
<discl>Discipline</discl>
<distrib>
<emphasis type="u"></emphasis></distrib>
<expcont></expcont>
<destr>Destruction</destr>
<authnot></authnot>
<pubdate></pubdate></idinfo>
<lep>
<lepcontents autobuild="1"></lep>
<contents autobuild="1">
<illuslist autobuild="1">
<tablelist autobuild="1">
<foreword>
<!--#start#-->
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title></title>
<para>
This text should be in the new file</para></para0>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title></title>
<para>
<!--#stop#-->
<acronym>
<def></def>
<term></term></acronym></para></para0>
<?Pub Caret -2></foreword>
<safesum>
<para0 verdate="5/2/16" verstatus="ver">
<title>
</title>
<para>
</para>
</para0></safesum></front>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter id="chap1">
<title>Chapter 1</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Paragraph 1</title>
<para></para></para0></chapter>
<chapter id="chap2">
<title>Chapter 2</title>
<section id="thoery_of_operation_section">
<title></title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Paragraph 2</title>
<para>
<!--#start#-->
<change level="1" change="delete">
<emphasis type="u" color="blue">
<xref xrefid="fig2-1">Figure 1 Smelly Fish</emphasis></change>
<!--#stop#-->
</para></para0></section>
<section>
<title></title>
<para0>
<title></title></para0></section></chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

The results should be just the elements in between the markers.

```
<prtitle>
<subject>
Trying to get this code to work</subject></prtitle>
<mfr></mfr>
<contractno>A12345</contractno>
<contractno>B12</contractno>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Para0 Title</title>
<para>
This text should be in the new file</para></para0>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title></title>
<para>
<acronym>
<def>definition</def>
<term>Look here</term></acronym></para>
<change level="1" change="delete">
<emphasis type="u" color="blue">
<xref xrefid="fig2-1">Figure 1 Smelly Fish</emphasis></change>
```

Thank you for all the help,
Max

Comment: Where are `startMark` and `stopMark` defined?

Comment: I'm sorry I updated the code to show you

Comment: The code work on my machine. I would suggest you split the logic into smaller method to test them properly. Have you verified if the backup file is there with the actual that you want when the ReadAllLines is executed? Does it contain the right path?

Comment: I don't see a problem either. Maybe your file is corrupt because you have start tags with no matching stop tags. In those cases you will get "<!--#start#-->" in the output file.

Comment: I just don't know. I'm trying it every which way. It's strange it's working for you. iI changed the start/stop so they always match and got the same bad results. So you are getting the selected text and only the selected?

Comment: Yes. The ".bak" file has just the selected text.

Comment: I'm still getting the bad results. I"m in Visual Studio using VB windows form project. You would be using VS too and if so what type of project did you use?

Comment: Maybe there's extra characters in your line like a space. What happen when you put a breakpoint?

Comment: VS has a debugger - you should use it. Step through your program and add watches on the `line` and `insideBlock` variables.

Comment: I did and it looks right. I'm just not getting the output correctly. Grrr

Comment: It's reading the insideBlock true/false correctly but not writing the line to the document

Comment: Thank you guys I got it working